# FLASK Unable to change CSS with JS file

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

Trying to change the background with my URL input using jinja2/flask alongside python/javascript.

The alert works. Background color doesn't however. Works on a file that only has html/js/py.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
    <title>♟️Checkerboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        {{output}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Python**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello(): 
    output = "hello world"
    return render_template('index.html', output = output)

if __name__=="__main__":  
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
alert("Testing");
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Basically all file links have proven to work.
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; proven to work.
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; doesn't work in jinja/flask.

Please help.

Comment: You could try moving the script declaration inside and at the bottom of the body. That's where they're usually placed anyways.

Comment: It worked!!!!
You just saved me hours of endless fighting with my computer lol.
Thank you! It's always the little things!

Comment: I know the feeling.. Glad I could help!